# TikZ: Connect "normal" coordinates with coordinates in a scope environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, arc, latexit

I am trying to achieve something like this in TikZ with LaTeXiT to use it in a non TeX environment as an .svg or .png:

[image]

With this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    %Center
    \coordinate[label=below:Z] (Z) at (3.5,1);
    \fill[black] (Z) circle (0.875mm);
    \fill[white, label=hi] (Z) circle (0.625mm);

    %Original triangle
    \coordinate[label=right:A](A) at (2,2);
    \coordinate[label=below:B](B) at (1,0);
    \coordinate[label=below:C](C) at (0,0);
    \draw[black,line width=0.5mm] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle node at (-0.5,0) [black,above left] {Original};

    %Rotated triangle
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={-160:(Z)}]
        \coordinate[label=below:A'](A) at (2,2);
        \coordinate[label=below left:B'](B) at (1,0);
        \coordinate[label=right:C'](C) at (0,0);
        \draw[black,line width=0.5mm,dashed] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle node at (0.5,1) [black,right] {Bild};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And with help of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142425/rotate-a-path-around-a-point) (and lots of trying around before finding this..) I got this far, but I have no idea how to proceed to connect those coordinates with an arc. Or is my approach completely wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

After just a bit more of googling, I found out that I can simply use the names of the coordinates in the scope environment.

So this code emerged and solved my issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone} % Remove font size option when using LaTeXiT, or you'll risk the clipping problem I encountered (see below)

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    %Center
    \coordinate[label=below:Z] (Z) at (3.5,1);
    \fill[black] (Z) circle (0.875mm);
    \fill[white] (Z) circle (0.625mm);

    %Original triangle
    \coordinate[label=right:A](A) at (2,2);
    \coordinate[label=below:B](B) at (1,0);
    \coordinate[label=below:C](C) at (0,0);
    \draw[black,line width=0.5mm] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle node at (-0.5,0) [black,above left] {Original};

    %Rotated triangle
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={-160:(Z)}]
        \coordinate[label=below:A'](A2) at (2,2);
        \coordinate[label=below left:B'](B2) at (1,0);
        \coordinate[label=right:C'](C2) at (0,0);
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=2.693cm,arc=l,helpline](B2,Z,B);
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=3.640cm,arc=l,helpline](C2,Z,C);
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.803cm,arc=l,helpline](A2,Z,A);
        \draw[black,line width=0.5mm,dashed] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- cycle node at (0.5,1) [black,right] {Bild};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

And yes the radius of the arc is calculated by hand.

And now I have to find out why the f* C' and "Bild" isn't showing?

Comment: After adding `\usetkzobj{all}`, I get the `C'` and `Bild` nodes, but the dashed triangle is drawn above the original one. I needed to draw the dashed lines between `A2`, `B2` and `C2`, not `A`, `B` and `C`, to get it in the correct place. (Edit: With TeX Live 2016, TikZ version 3.0.1a, `tkz-euclide` version 1.16c.)

Comment: Oh man, i used `A2`, `B2` and `C2` too of course. I'll edit it. And yea you're right `\usetkzobj{all}` is used too. But when I use TexShop or similar I also get the `Bild` and `C'` but using LaTeXiT I don't?  (also Tex Live 2016 and TikZ 3.0.1a and tkz-euclide 1.16c)

Comment: Hmm.. adding a further coordinate at around `(8,0)` fixes the problem for LaTeXiT.. I'll go with that botched method until I have a better solution :)

Comment: I don't know LaTeXit, but seems like it is a bit too aggressive when it comes to cropping.

Comment: Wow.. LaTeXiT has an option to define the font size. Now when I define the font size in the preamble with `\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}` AND in LaTeXiT I get those cropped svg's. But using `\documentclass{standalone}` and setting the font size only in LaTeXiT removes the clipping problem. Glad I got it working though.